# WSO2CEP 4.2.0 error: A mandatory attribute null does not exist

Tags: wso2, wso2-cep

We are using WSO2CEP version 4.2.0.  We are connecting to a MySQL database (version 5.6.34-1 community edition from Oracle) on the back-end with mysql-connector-java-5.1.40.jar.  We have set up several connections in the master-datasources.xml, and receive "Connection is healthy" for all connections when testing them in Datasources.  When we attempt to use an event publisher that accesses the referenced databases an error appears:

> [2017-01-24 17:11:22,178] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.event.publisher.admin.EventPublisherAdminService} -  org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.core.exception.OutputEventAdapterRuntimeException: A mandatory attribute null does not exist
>   org.wso2.carbon.event.publisher.core.exception.EventPublisherConfigurationException: org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.core.exception.OutputEventAdapterRuntimeException: A mandatory attribute null does not exist
>           at org.wso2.carbon.event.publisher.core.EventPublisherDeployer.processDeployment(EventPublisherDeployer.java:227)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.event.publisher.core.EventPublisherDeployer.executeManualDeployment(EventPublisherDeployer.java:249)
>   .........several lines after this ...............

Our team are kind of at a loss, we have tried things like giving blanket permissions including DDL to the database user, trying an old database that "used to work", and changing out versions of the mysql-connector-java jar.

Comment: We have found where the error originates in the code, it is in RDBMSEventAdapter.java:548: https://github.com/wso2/carbon-analytics-common/blob/0824ddc494e605e93a775dd01691f7d9ceaeb226/components/event-publisher/event-output-adapters/org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.rdbms/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/event/output/adapter/rdbms/RDBMSEventAdapter.java . It appears that the code is iterating over a feature set, trying to see if the database connection supports those features? Not entirely sure but why is is saying "null" is not supported? Shouldn't it list what's missing?

Answer (score 0):

We found that we had a configuration problem - invalid XML in output-event-adapters.xml that was causing the error. Bad XML fixed, error gone.

WSO2, please consider addressing error verbosity in your products. The error that was being logged provided no indication that invalid XML might be the cause, and we wasted several hours troubleshooting the problem as a result. We have experienced similar error-verbosity-related issues in other WSO2 products. A simple "could not parse XML" with the file name would have literally saved us several hours this time.